# Recover files from corrupted SD card from Windows

Tags: raspbian, sd-card, pi-2, noobs

About a year ago I installed NOOBS on an SD card, then put raspbian on the SD card using NOOBS, and it's always worked fine, however I now have a problem where whenever I boot into raspbian I get "Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(179,2)". After looking around this seems to be due to a corrupted partition on the SD card. I hosted my website using this SD card, and I forgot to make any backups. From windows, how can I recover those files, without Linux or fsck?
I'm using Windows 10, and I have a card reader and I can access NOOBS's RECOVERY partition, which doesn't appear to contain anything useful. I was using a pi 2 B.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The SD card will have two partitions.

A small FAT formatted partition used for the boot files (abour 60 MB).

A large ext4 formatted partition used for everything else.

Windows does not understand the ext4 format.

You will need to boot your Windows machine from a Live Linux CD.

Google for examples, e.g. https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/377416:the-five-best-linux-live-cds

This will turn your PC into a temporary Linux machine, without altering your Windows set up.

You will then be able to view the SD card if your PC has a SD card reader and save any files to a USB stick.

Comment: The [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) Live disk should work and be fairly easy to use - however it may be missing some helpful packages so the [GParted Live CD](http://gparted.org/livecd.php) may work better.

Comment: I'm looking for a Windows based option

Comment: @Matthew see the OP's answer to http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/39391/cant-stop-script-from-running-at-start-up and search for paragon.